# Which Star Trek episode featured humanoids who have a one-month life span?

Tags: star-trek, episode-identification

In this Star Trek episode, the crew visits a planet which seems a lot like Earth, but it turns out the inhabitants have a life span of only 30 days, if I remember correctly. Since their life spans are so accelerated compared to Earth's inhabitants, they are very quick to fall in love with the Enterprise crew members. After all, they expect to die within just a few days.

Did I dream this plot? I can't find any reference to it.

Edit

> This question is answered! Thank you. The TV show in I was asking about is actually from Stargate SG-1, season 1, titled "Brief Candle."- Raoul Snidjiik

Comment: Can you remember anything else about the episode? Any of the characters, for example? Might help us place it (especially if it's not actually *Star Trek*, which seems plausible)

Comment: I believe this was actually an episode of Stargate SG-1, but I'm not at a place where I can find more details at the moment.

Comment: That does sound like the SG-1 episode Brief Candle http://imdb.com/rg/an_share/title/title/tt0709052/

Comment: This question is answered! Thank you. The TV show in I was asking about is actually from Stargate SG-1, season 1, titled "Brief Candle."

Comment: @RaoulSnidjik If the question is answered please remember to accept the correct answer.

Comment: The shortest lifespan I remember hearing of in a *Star Trek* episode is the one with the suicidal Q, who mentions some crewmember's nine-year lifespan.

Comment: @Medinoc That crew member would be [Kes](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Kes) from VOY

Comment: If you found my answer to be helpful dont forget to accept it thanks

Comment: Given the story ID of SG-1 "Brief Candle" and that the inhabitants had 100 day life spans, I wonder if the 30 day value you mention came from the estimated remainder of O'Neill's life.

Answer (score 61):

This sounds like "Brief Candle", from Stargate SG1. [wiki](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Brief_Candle)

> On a visit to Argos, SG-1 discover that a Goa'uld, Pelops, engineered the Argosian race to live for only 100 days. Colonel Jack O'Neill is inadvertently infected with the nanites that cause their rapid aging and grows older by the day, while the team try to stop the process before it is too late. The Argosians treat SG-1 very well and one woman, Kynthia, takes a strong liking to Colonel Jack O'Neill; they have lots of close contact.

The close contact if remember rightly involves some kissing/other/loveydovey.

Comment: Yup, that's the one I was thinking of.

Comment: I'm checking out "Brief Candle" right now. I guess it's SG-1 and not STOS. Wow. I'm getting old. I used to be pretty good at keeping the various Star* series and movies straight. Scary.

Comment: Yep, it looks like I was thinking of "Brief Candle." I guess I should be glad I'm not mixing up episodes of "The Sopranos", "The FBI" and "Mr. Ed" -- not yet, anyway. I do generally still get my wife's name right, though. (Or worse, mixing up an episode of "Mr. Ed" with the plot of "The Godfather" -- ewe. Sorry, Ed.)

Comment: @RaoulSnidjik also if this is correct dont forget to accept this answer.

Comment: Umm, how to I "accept this answer"? I added a comment below that accepts the answer, but I don't see any way to tag or flag this thread as solved. Thanks.

Comment: @RaoulSnidjik under the up and down vote arrows, is a checkmark, if you press it it turns green.

Answer (score 18):

It sounds like you are describing [Wink of an Eye](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Wink_of_an_Eye_%28episode%29). That episode featured the [Scalosians](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Scalosian), whose

> bio-chemistry had accelerated to a point that they experienced hours as other lifeforms experienced minutes. Once a nation of 900,000, their numbers rapidly declined until there were only five of them left by 2268.
>
> In 2268, they hijacked the USS Enterprise in an effort to repopulate their race with the male crew.

Comment: Sounds close, but the pics I found online look like another episode. I think my memory is skewed. Thank you, though.

Comment: Must have been sweeps week that episode.

Comment: @T.E.D. "I do not understand why Kirk, the largest of the Star Trekkers, does not simply *eat* the other crewmembers?"

Comment: You mean "experienced seconds as other lifeforms experienced minutes"?

Comment: @Bobby To the Scalosians, it seems like everyone is moving in slow motion. In the time you experience minutes, they will experience hours. 'As' is a little ambiguous in this phrasing. In the quote 'as' = 'while', in your phrase, 'as' = 'like'.

Comment: There was never an explicit mention of the acceleration factor, so 30-day life span would not fit this story.

Answer (score 13):

You might be thinking of the TOS episode [Miri](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0394905/?ref_=ttep_ep9) as there are several overlaps.

The planet is definitely an Earth clone.  The main difference is that the people, due to a genetically engineered virus, have significantly slowed aging.  *However*, once they hit puberty, the virus becomes deadly within 30 days.  The main guest star is a girl about to hit puberty who becomes infatuated with Kirk.

Guest stars you might recognize:

Titular character Miri is played by Kim Darby (aka Mattie Ross from the original True Grit and the mom from Better Off Dead"

Her friend Jahn is played by Michael J Pollard (character actor most likely remembered from Scrooged, Tango & Cash, and as Mr. Mxyzptlk in Superboy tv series)

Answer (score 8):

I just realized you found the answer in a Stargate episode, but this reminded me of Deep Space Nine's episode [Meridian](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Meridian_(episode)).

In it, the crew finds a planet that's only "in phase" for a short time- the rest of the time, it is incorporeal and cannot be reached from our universe. They use their corporeal time to fall in love, and one of them falls in love with Jadzia Dax.